# Encoding message with publickey in javascript and decode it with privatekey in python

Tags: javascript, python, encryption

I had cryptography lessons some time ago and I didn't use this knowledge for too long. I cannot find the solution to my problem. I want to encrypt the password given by the user in html form with public key using JavaScript. Then I want to decode the password in the backend with python using the private key.

I have private key and public key generated with [cryptography](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/rsa/) package in Python. This is my code:

```
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import rsa
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization
private_key = rsa.generate_private_key(public_exponent=65537, key_size=1024, backend=default_backend())
public_key = private_key.public_key()
tmp = public_key.public_bytes(encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM, format=serialization.PublicFormat.SubjectPublicKeyInfo)
pubKeySerial = tmp
pubKeySerial = ""
for pLine in tmp.splitlines(): 
    if("---" not in pLine):
        pubKeySerial = pubKeySerial + pLine
```

The private key looks like that:

> -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
>   MIICXAIBAAKBgQC/imA04asbusVtcSsM9KVdZE7ISeEPfzktIxtkGgVP8S4qUdN2 gh9nL+/8+J1SKBrltmWDRxByqdi36EyyqPRg9rAcY6VXJI4nHEiHHrtLdAUlxyAe
>   hnAvOEnCEqeKHmbcTsnilJRJfcf7ecFxwmrGBLQ4i1YLOWR/9NDXlox0/QIDAQAB
>   AoGAVD0weLFzRpvK7ooiC+2guMU/3NiZMe6bH93b0xealIEW86fPH8S0uPYdTx2s
>   WxCmW7bvSGA9vKA0XxW8farO5v7lxc4VJkefPuTeJo+oJ1+jV5VCTnQsgAjrXieP
>   T4MtxO6U77xUnyWlWDAdvWbc+LreVpmru77SHDVYJ7ZxcaUCQQDuk/7gAHhMgAC8
>   ZCK6XhoAfrYhh1hl5/Ynqb885p/l/cjnvi3cImaslOpmJ4aav15iZSC6Di0jmrDU
>   njZBABmDAkEAzYcOBEwX/dDlffcsYFNKKYrUpTK09pMuYqLO5RabGNMEUW//EVAc
>   +QnyCht0eJaZL93NM5KWHGpY57BFhtBvfwJAOL/hX50dAG1uP2G+VQBvRPDfF+ie 4Vak2dhp0e212Tpd4Kn/NJ7GN4UQoI4EWajtpZASkc8vc4mnSFv94cZJSwJAKxR4
>   +quch8ZGpE2wDozGychg5DOpvNmC6ofnyBsh7WUlzZAlLdLWD9lm03mHw1MFzwO1 5G6AanpcIkxPdn+wLwJBAJFXD2HfzFBuFqM9XPq6GKOHomyok7y1iQ+E+BO/WzEu
>   IMos+RRGH88YwdndajP7ksRCiv5xOhmS93mINwdhVy8=
>   -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

And the public key looks like that (the *pubKeySerial* variable):

> MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDkLspl01zeWMBm+LCs+AhT98TSpzg0fqnfvnVv1mejHRJsMP44BgkElQPLnUTKmKNWjZtx2wuYPOymNdqfVCe1XB/6634x3FDmrdkv6QBWXn5TI+WQ1AXxV7NsglIzaxNkYxBXdPGQl7MKkaEQnMq8zZeJueUx5W9Ec8pwGrigawIDAQAB

I pass the public key to javascript and encode some password written in the html form with [cryptico](https://github.com/wwwtyro/cryptico):

```
var encrypted = cryptico.encrypt(password, publicKey);
```

The *password* is just a word. The *publicKey* has exactly the same value as *pubKeySerial* variable written above. After the code above, for the password *mypassword*, the *encrypted.cipher* variable takes value:

> A8fe4LUhPTIIcN86B8Cd5mHe7RpXKyNCT5yzMh5qvwjuT3u7m7VIGWW/OjMoJ3uzE6tRHCTvBE2WyNKZujJLfdQ9nYTdhf05dja2y4yoIeyNObDe0KMfePlNtnnGR0vu0LSdSmwGxx+RPifs2OQ3NQaPVIq+YliROKUQGwKvvUUs/8SqkZFjQbQlcJu7p5X9Eo6X6TxUsT1WA93UUIVobfXC?oh4aFfA4xRuHDPOlz1HW3dibQg5cUMZ+4n+HSH7h9sY=

I pass the *encrypted.cipher* value to the python in the backend. The *encrypted.cipher* value is in the *self.password* variable in the code below:

```
from settings import private_key
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import padding
plaintext = private_key.decrypt(self.password, padding.OAEP(mgf=padding.MGF1(algorithm=hashes.SHA1()), algorithm=hashes.SHA1(), label=None))
```

In the *plaintext* line I receive the error:

> Ciphertext length must be equal to key size.

I have no idea what to do with that... I tried mixing other cryptography packages like [pyOpenSSL](http://www.pyopenssl.org/en/stable/introduction.html) or [jsencrypt](https://github.com/travist/jsencrypt) and I always get the error above.

Please help. Thank you for all the comments in advance.

Comment: `cryptico` does more than just an asymmetric encryption. It actually generates an AES key, uses that to symmetrically encrypt the data, and then encrypts the AES key via RSA (https://github.com/wwwtyro/cryptico#encryption-1). So simply calling decrypt on the Python side is insufficient, you'll need to determine the serialization format (which will let you get the RSA encrypted payload, the initialization vector of the symmetric payload, and the symmetric payload itself), and the RSA encryption padding.

Comment: Thank you for comment. From what you've written I guess that my mistake is that I use simply: "private_key.decrypt(self.password, padding.OAEP(mgf=padding.MGF1(algorithm=hashes.SHA1()), algorithm=hashes.SHA1(), label=None))". I should then examine what padding I have to use there to properly response to what cryptico did, right? I will take a look at that. However, I am not really good in the cryptography and I don't know where to look for that. I would appreciate some hints in that matter.